# How to get data of the middle table in many to many relationship in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a question in sequelize orm. 
There is Many to Many relationship between tables , through a middle table.

```js
 const Tag = sequelize.define('tag', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    type: Sequelize.CHAR
  })
  const Image = sequelize.define('image', {
    thumb: Sequelize.STRING,
    original: Sequelize.STRING,
    status: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    width: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    height:   Sequelize.INTEGER,
    fileSize:  Sequelize.STRING,
  })

const TagImages = sequelize.define('TagImages', {
    value: Sequelize.STRING,
})
```

When I find an image by Id , I get all tags well by include, But I cannot get the **value** column in tagImages table.

This is my query statement:

```js
Image.findById(imageId,{ include: [Tag] })
    .then(image => {
        console.log(image);
    })
```

and there is no column of **value** in my console.log. How should I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize should put a `TagImage` property on each included `Tag`.